# Multiple Box Plots on Top of Each Other

Tags: pgfplots

I have multiple box plots on top of each other - see the two black box plots in the "400 Iterations" entry - there should be only one (since I'm cycling through the colors), and one of the black plots is missing from the "600 Iterations" entry. (Also there is weird issue where some of the whiskers don't render properly - see the red plot in the "0 Iterations" entry).

Here is my example. Thanks!

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    boxplot/draw direction=y,
    ylabel={Fitness (\# $t$-sets separated)},
    xlabel={\# Iterations},
    height=8cm,
    boxplot={
        %
        % Idea: 
        %  place the 
        %  group 1 at 0.3333 and 0.6666
        %  group 2 at 1.3333 and 1.6666
        %  group 3 at 2.3333 and 2.6666
        %  ...
        % in a formular:
        draw position={1/6 + floor(\plotnumofactualtype/5) + 1/6*mod(\plotnumofactualtype,5)},
        %
        % that means the box extend must be at most 0.33333 :
        box extend=0.16,
    },
    % ... it also means that 1 unit in x controls the width:
    x=3cm,
    % ... and it means that we should describe intervals:
    xtick={0,1,2,...,30},
    x tick label as interval,
    xticklabels={%
        0,200,400,600,800,1000
    },
    x tick label style={
        text width=3cm,
        align=center
    },
    cycle list={black,red,blue,orange,pink}
    ]

    % 0
    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        18869\\
        19034\\
        19037\\
        19040\\
        19132\\
    };
    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        19137\\
        19233\\
        19234.5\\
        19236\\
        19327\\
    };
    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        19051\\
        19145\\
        19145.5\\
        19146\\
        19215\\
    };
    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        19030\\
        19149\\
        19149.5\\
        19150\\
        19248\\
    };
    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        19035\\
        19167\\
        19167.5\\
        19168\\
        19236\\
    };

    % 200
    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        18869\\
        19126\\
        19128.5\\
        19131\\
        19262\\
    };
    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        19137\\
        19287\\
        19288\\
        19289\\
        19403\\
    };
    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        19051\\
        19199\\
        19202.5\\
        19206\\
        19295\\
    };
    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        19030\\
        19217\\
        19217.5\\
        19218\\
        19328\\
    };
    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        19070\\
        19212\\
        19213\\
        19214\\
        19307\\
    };

    % 400
    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        18869\\
        19221\\
        19223\\
        19226\\
        19341\\
    };
    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        19137\\
        19351\\
        19351.5\\
        19352\\
        19412\\
    };
    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        19051\\
        19252\\
        19254\\
        19256\\
        19324\\
    };
    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        19030\\
        19266\\
        19267\\
        19268\\
        19347\\
    };
    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        19087\\
        19257\\
        19258.5\\
        19260\\
        19340\\
    };

    % 600
    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        18869\\
        19034\\
        19037\\
        19040\\
        19132\\
    };
    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        19185\\
        19376\\
        19377\\
        19378\\
        19420\\
    };
    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        19051\\
        19273\\
        19273.5\\
        19274\\
        19353\\
    };
    \addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
    data\\
    19030\\
    19307\\
    19307\\
    19307\\
    19350\\
};
    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        19087\\
        19307\\
        19309\\
        19311\\
        19384\\
    };

    % 800
    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        18932\\
        19375\\
        19377\\
        19379\\
        19419\\
    };
    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        19185\\
        19388\\
        19388\\
        19388\\
        19420\\
    };
    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        19051\\
        19312\\
        19312.5\\
        19313\\
        19359\\
    };
    \addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
    data\\
    19030\\
    19266\\
    19267\\
    19268\\
    19347\\
};
    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        19092\\
        19339\\
        19339.5\\
        19340\\
        19400\\
    };

    % 1000
    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        18944\\
        19405\\
        19405\\
        19405\\
        19432\\
    };
    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        19185\\
        19394\\
        19394.5\\
        19395\\
        19420\\
    };
    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        19051\\
        19333\\
        19333.5\\
        19334\\
        19362\\
    };
    \addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
    data\\
    19030\\
    19266\\
    19267\\
    19268\\
    19347\\
};
    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        19135\\
        19377\\
        19378\\
        19379\\
        19409\\
    };

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're seeing is some numerical imprecision/rounding error or similar. If you divide by 4.9 instead of 5 in the `floor` function, you get the correct output:

```
draw position={1/6 + floor(\plotnumofactualtype/4.9) + 1/6*mod(\plotnumofactualtype,5)},
```

[image]

Regarding the whiskers, looks like the upper whisker ends up almost equal to the upper quartile. Have you tried calculating it manually, following the description in the `pgfplots` manual, to check whether the display is as it should or not?